# Having trouble loading jquery into WordPress using many methods

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I've now tried several methods to load jquery into wordpress and can't get anything to work. I've tried injecting code directly into wp-config.php, tried using the Use Google Libraries plugin and tried different code in my functions.php file and nothing will work. I've even tried adding jquery directly via cdn to my header and footer files and neither works.

Can anyone think of anything else I can try to get it to work or does anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue?

functions.php:

```
<?php

function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('my-custom-menu',__( 'My Custom Menu' ));
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );

function enqueue_stylesheets() {

    //For registering Styles

    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css');

    wp_enqueue_style('fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700|Raleway:400,500,600,700,900');

    wp_enqueue_style('fontAwesome', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css');

    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapCSS', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');


    //For registering Scripts files
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapJS', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.4', true );

    wp_register_script('navbarScroll', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/navbarScroll.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );

    wp_enqueue_script('navbarScroll');

    wp_register_script( 'navbarScroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.navbarScroll.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'navbarScroll' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_stylesheets' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove last 2 argument Or you can enter only argument which having data, please don't pass like (' ') in the argument.
Check the below example.

```
/**
 * Enqueue a script with jQuery as a dependency.
 */ 
function wpdocs_scripts_method () {
  wp_enqueue_script ('custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri (). '/Js/custom_script. js', array ('jquery'));
} 
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_scripts_method');
```

Also check that JS is exists or not in the destination folder

Answer (score 0):

In functions.php :

```
function enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.11.2');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );
```

Hope this will help you.